# Is it possible to connect other devices to a Nest and pass the data via the API?

Tags: nest-api

I can't find confirmation one way or another in the developer documents, but is it possible to connect additional sensors to the Nest and query their data via the API? I would like to send heat pump data along with the Nest data, much like you can [do with Ecobee's sensors](https://www.ecobee.com/home/developer/api/documentation/v1/objects/Sensor.shtml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in the current program.